# IndexError: string index out of range issue

Tags: python, node.js, performance

can you help me to solve this error, I already made modifications in my code but it keeps sending me the same one, I no longer understand or I can't see what I have to do.
I share how my code looks like it is done in python

here in js worked but in python there is an error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0CfE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXaKW.png)

```
def userID_decoding(string):
    arr = []
    string = "," + string
    # print(string)
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if len(string) == 0:
          print("Error: Empty string passed")
          return
        arr.append(string[i])
        print(arr)
        if arr[i] == "," and i > 0:
            string = string[:i-1] + string[i:]
            print(string)
    string = string[:len(string)-1]
    print(string)
    print(cadena.replace(",", "").replace("\"", ""))
```

I'm trying to decode numbers so that I can get analytics emails back this my code js but i'm try to  conver in paython

```
function userID_decoding(str) {
    var arr = [];
    str = "," + str;
    console.log(str)
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = str.charAt(i);
        if (arr[i] == "," && i > 0) {
            str = str.slice(0, i - 1) + str.slice(i);
            console.log(str);
        }
    }
    str = str.slice(0, str.length - 1);
    console.log(str);
    return unescape(str.replace(/((,)|(\"))/g, "%u00"));
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, as it has, among other issues, [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: No need to show the js code and its better to post the console output as text, not an image. We can't copy from an image.

Comment: `string = string[:i-1] + string[i:]` makes the string shorter but you iterate for the full length of the original string. I haven't figured out what this code is supposed to do. Can you say what the goal is? One of the differeneces is that the js code keeps reading the length in `i < str.length` but the python code only uses the original length. This code seems to put commas in takes commas out.... confusing. Is it just `"," + string.replace(",", "")`? That is, have a leading comma and remove other commas?